# React Native "Cannot find module 'react-native'" Problem

Tags: react-native

I installed `react-native` and the global cli.

But when I run `npm start`, I'm having this error:

```bash
Cannot find module 'react-native'
```

Here is my `App.js` file. Thank you...

```js
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, View, Text } from "react-native";

function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
      >
        <View style={{ flex: 3 }}>
          <Text>Kayıt Listesi</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execute the following steps:

1. Remove your `node_modules` directory.
2. Run `npm install`.
3. Run `npm start`.

The command `npm install` install everything your project needs into the `node_modules` directory.

If this does not help, try to add `react-native` individually by executing the command `npm install react-native --save`.

It is usually a good idea to initialize a new project using `npm init`, which creates a `package.json` file in which `npm` stores names and versions of all installed packages.

**Edit:** After we have investigated the whole stack trace it is apparent that we need to install `react-native-web` via the command `npm install react-native-web`.